# Text on video ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I add text overlay on my video in ffmpeg?

i.e. given a video "video1.flv", how can I add "StackOverflow" text during the whole video, positioned in the middle of the screen, with white text and a border?

Comment: **The "ffmpeg" tag is only allowed for programmatic use of the ffmpeg API** - Questions about the command-line use should be asked on Super-user or Video-production.

Answer (score 274):

Use the [drawtext filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for simple text on video. If you need more complex timing, formatting, or dynamic text see the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles). This answer focuses on the drawtext filter.

## Example

[image: Text centered on video]

Print `Stack Overflow` in white text onto center of video, with black background box of 50% opacity:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

- The audio is stream copied in this example (like a copy and paste).
- `@0.5` controls background box opacity. 0.5 is 50%. Remove `@0.5` if you do not want any transparency.
- See the [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for a complete list and explanations of options.

## Preview

You can use `ffplay` to preview your text without having to wait for a file to encode:

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" input.mp4
```

Alternatively you can use `mpv` but the [syntax](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#video-filters) is slightly different:

```
mpv --vf="lavfi=[drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2]" input.mp4
```

## Multiple texts

You can chain multiple drawtext filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2,drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Bottom right text':fontcolor=black:fontsize=14:x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

## Position

`x` and `y` determine text position:

| Position | `x`:`y` | With 10 px padding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Top left | `x=0:y=0` | `x=10:y=10` |
| Top center | `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=0` | `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10` |
| Top right | `x=w-tw:y=0` | `x=w-tw-10:y=10` |
| Centered | `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2` |  |
| Bottom left | `x=0:y=h-th` | `x=10:y=h-th-10` |
| Bottom center | `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th` | `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-10` |
| Bottom right | `x=w-tw:y=h-th` | `x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10` |
| Random | See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363661/) |  |

## Repositioning text on demand

You can reposition the text with the [sendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) and [zmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) filters:

- [sendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) if you have predetermined positions and timing. See [Sendcmd in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600924/) and [FFmpeg drawtext filter - is it possible to use variables with live data for x,y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966056/)
- [zmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) for live, on-the-fly positioning. See [ffmpeg cli filter that require user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990114/).

## Moving / animated / looping / scrolling text

See:

- [ffmpeg moving text drawtext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498026/)
- [Loop text that wipes left to right using FFMPEG drawtext filter](https://superuser.com/a/875363/)
- [Scrolling from RIGHT to LEFT in ffmpeg / drawtext](https://superuser.com/a/1026814/110524)

## Timing

Use the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) to control when the text appears.

Show text between 5-10 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:enable='between(t,5,10)'" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Show text after 3 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:enable='gte(t,3)'" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Blinking text. For every 10 seconds show text for 5 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:enable='lt(mod(t,10),5)'" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Random position every 30 seconds:

See [ffmpeg - Dynamic letters and random position watermark to video?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363661/)

## Changing / updating text

Add the `textfile` and `reload` options for drawtext:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:textfile=text.txt:reload=1:fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

- Update `text.txt` every time you want the text to change.
- **Important:** You must update the text file *atomically* or it may fail. You can do this with the `mv` command on Linux or macOS.
- If you have many text changes, such as making subtitles, it is easier to make a subtitle file (such as an `.ass` file via Aegisub) and using the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles).

## Font family instead of font file

You can declare the font family, such as *Times New Roman*, instead of having to point to a font file. See [How to include font in FFMPEG command without using the fontfile option?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027999/)

## Requirements

The drawtext filter requires `ffmpeg` to be compiled with `--enable-libfreetype`. If you get `No such filter: 'drawtext'` it is missing `--enable-libfreetype`. Most of the `ffmpeg` static builds available support this: see the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links.

Comment: Thank you.  This produces text that is static.  Other than date/time features, is there a way to produce an overlay of text that changes (such as a ticker tape at the bottom of the screen) or input from a text stream?

Comment: @NoahTernullo there's also strftime options and "pts" variable you can use.  In terms of making it ticker along the bottom, you can probably use some function for x variable value changes based on pts or frame number.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard see my question here :http://stackoverflow.com/q/37404476/6127411. And please help me if you can.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have faced some problem. How to add special character in my watermark text? Here I posted question. Please answer me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266469/ffmpeg-utf-8-special-character-not-working-in-video-watermark-text

Comment: fyi, for those installing with brew, you can pass that flag `--with-libefreetype` to the install command.

Comment: Have tryed on Armbian:  ffmpeg -i rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/home/projekt/StreamTest/DejaVuSans.ttf: \
text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=36: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \
boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm  but I don't get any text in my stream..  also th --enable-libfreetype is present when i run ffmpeg

Comment: @Ferguson Provide a link to a pastebin that shows the complete `ffmpeg` console output. Does it work if you output to a local file such as `output.mp4`? I know nothing of FFM (FFserver live feed), so I won't be helpful for anything to do with `ffserver`.

Comment: @chovy I think the homebrew option you mentioned should be `--with-freetype`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard can you please look into this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018082/error-initializing-filter-drawtext-with-args-in-android)

Comment: @Eftekhari I believe [RTL is problematic with libfreetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931448/ffmpeg-drawtext-how-to-set-direction-right-to-left) (the library used by drawtext). You may have better results using the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter with ASS files.

Comment: add `:enable='between(t,00:00:15,00:00:20)` to specify the text duration, something like `ffmpeg -i part02.mp4 -vf drawtext="text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \
boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: enable='between(t,00:00:15,00:00:20)" -codec:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: I have created pastebin account and posted code there,check out it - 

https://pastebin.com/iupjh8Cx

Comment: @VivekThummar It needs to be in the form of `-vf "scale=1920:1080,drawtext=..."` Notice the comma (`,`) connecting the filters. The comma is missing in your command being executed. This is a problem with your implementation of the ffmpeg command in android.

Comment: Warning: This will re-encode your video and thus degrade quality. If you don't to lose quality on the re-encode you'll have to set additional parameters.

Comment: If you want to include a literal single quote `'` in your text, escape it “the CSV way”, by preceding it with another single quote: `text='I don''t know'`

Answer (score 5):

Here is the cheat sheet for overlay transition in all 4 direction...

```
************************* Text **********************

1) left to right given x=41 position 

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Hi': y=53.48 :x=min(t*250-2*250\,41): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,2,10)', drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Ajeet': y=53.48 :x=min(t*250-3*250\,90): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,3,10)' [out]" -t 11 leftToRight.mp4




2) right to left given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Hi': y=53.48 :x=w-min(t*250-2*250\,(w\-41)): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,2,10)', drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Ajeet': y=53.48 :x=w-min(t*250-3*250\,(w\-90)): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,3,10)' [out]" -t 11 rightToLeft.mp4




3) top to bottom given y=58 position 

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Hi': x=41 :y=min(t*250-2*250\,53.48): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,2,10)', drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Ajeet': x=90 :y=min(t*250-3*250\,53.48): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,3,10)' [out]" -t 11 topToBottom.mp4




4) bottom to up given y=90 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Hi': x=41 :y=h-min(t*250-2*250\,(h\-53.48)): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,2,10)', drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Ajeet': x=90 :y=h-min(t*250-3*250\,(h\-53.48)): fontsize=35: fontcolor=yellow: enable='between(t,3,10)' [out]" -t 11 bottomToTop.mp4
```

************************ Image *********************

```
1) single left to right given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=-2:100[png];[0:v][png]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:shortest=1:enable='between(t,2,10)'" -t 11 imageLeftToRight1.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181472383.sd.mp4?s=103f42915141758d95a118f070d08190845bdf73&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=-2:100[png];[0:v][png]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:shortest=1:enable='between(t,2,10)'" -t 11 imageLeftToRight.mp4




2) Already added text then added single image left to right

ffmpeg -y -i leftToRight.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=-2:100[png];[0:v][png]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=200:shortest=1:enable='between(t,2,10)'" -t 11 imageTextLeftToRight.mp4




3) 2 images left to right given x=41, x=100 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -loop 1 -i image2.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[img1];[2]scale=-2:100[img2];[0][img1]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][img2]overlay=x=min(t*250-3*250\,100):y=200:enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1" -t 11  multiImageLeftToRight.mp4




4) 3 images left to right given x=41, x=100, x=300 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -loop 1 -i image2.png -loop 1 -i image3.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[img1];[2]scale=-2:100[img2];[3]scale=-2:100[img3];[0][img1]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][img2]overlay=x=min(t*250-3*250\,130):y=130:enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][img3]overlay=x=min(t*250-4*250\,260):y=190:enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11  threeImageLeftToRight.mp4




5) 3 images right to left given x=41, x=100, x=300 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -loop 1 -i image2.png -loop 1 -i image3.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[img1];[2]scale=-2:100[img2];[3]scale=-2:100[img3];[0][img1]overlay=x=W-min(t*250-2*250\,(W\-41)):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][img2]overlay=x=W-min(t*250-3*250\,(W\-130)):y=130:enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][img3]overlay=x=W-min(t*250-4*250\,(W\-260)):y=190:enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11  threeImageRightToLeft.mp4




6) 3 images top to bottom given y=41, y=100, y=300 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -loop 1 -i image2.png -loop 1 -i image3.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[img1];[2]scale=-2:100[img2];[3]scale=-2:100[img3];[0][img1]overlay=x=41:y=min(t*250-2*250\,60):enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][img2]overlay=x=130:y=min(t*250-3*250\,130):enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][img3]overlay=x=260:y=min(t*250-4*250\,190):enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11  threeImageTopToBottom.mp4




7) 3 images bottom to top given y=41, y=100, y=300 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -loop 1 -i image.png -loop 1 -i image2.png -loop 1 -i image3.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[img1];[2]scale=-2:100[img2];[3]scale=-2:100[img3];[0][img1]overlay=x=41:y=H-min(t*250-2*250\,(H\-60)):enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][img2]overlay=x=130:y=H-min(t*250-3*250\,(H\-130)):enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][img3]overlay=x=260:y=H-min(t*250-4*250\,(H\-190)):enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11  threeImageBottomToTop.mp4
```

************************ GIF *********************

```
1) single left to right given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -ignore_loop 0 -i gif1.gif -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=-2:100[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)'" -t 11 gifLeftToRight.mp4




2) double left to right given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -ignore_loop 0 -i gif1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif2.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif3.gif -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[gif1];[2]scale=-2:100[gif2];[0][gif1]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][gif2]overlay=x=min(t*250-3*250\,150):y=170:enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1" -t 11 doubleGifLeftToRight.mp4




3) three left to right given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -ignore_loop 0 -i gif1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif2.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif3.gif -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[gif1];[2]scale=-2:100[gif2];[3]scale=-2:100[gif3];[0][gif1]overlay=x=min(t*250-2*250\,41):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][gif2]overlay=x=min(t*250-3*250\,150):y=170:enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][gif3]overlay=x=min(t*250-4*250\,240):y=240:enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11 threeGifLeftToRight.mp4



3) three right to left given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -ignore_loop 0 -i gif1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif2.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif3.gif -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[gif1];[2]scale=-2:100[gif2];[3]scale=-2:100[gif3];[0][gif1]overlay=x=W-min(t*250-2*250\,(W\-41)):y=60:enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][gif2]overlay=x=W-min(t*250-3*250\,(W\-150)):y=170:enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][gif3]overlay=x=W-min(t*250-4*250\,(W\-240)):y=240:enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11 threeGifRightToLeft.mp4




3) three top to bottom given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -ignore_loop 0 -i gif1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif2.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif3.gif -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[gif1];[2]scale=-2:100[gif2];[3]scale=-2:100[gif3];[0][gif1]overlay=x=41:y=min(t*250-2*250\,60):enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][gif2]overlay=x=150:y=min(t*250-3*250\,170):enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][gif3]overlay=x=240:y=min(t*250-4*250\,240):enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11 threeGifTopToBottom.mp4




3) three bottom to top given x=41 position

ffmpeg -y -i 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/181545195.sd.mp4?s=176d502710df829442a83565bb79efbe3c9c0b93&profile_id=164' -ignore_loop 0 -i gif1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif2.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i gif3.gif -filter_complex "[1]scale=-2:100[gif1];[2]scale=-2:100[gif2];[3]scale=-2:100[gif3];[0][gif1]overlay=x=41:y=H-min(t*250-2*250\,(H\-60)):enable='between(t,2,10)':shortest=1[o1];[o1][gif2]overlay=x=150:y=H-min(t*250-3*250\,(H\-170)):enable='between(t,3,10)':shortest=1[o2];[o2][gif3]overlay=x=240:y=H-min(t*250-4*250\,(H\-240)):enable='between(t,4,10)':shortest=1" -t 11 threeGifBottomToTop.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

### On macOS with enable='between(t,0,10)'

On macOS the syntax of **enable='between(t,start_second, end_seconds)'** is different. Input should be in seconds, not in hh:mm:ss.

My ffmpeg version 4.3.1

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='My Text':enable='between(t,20,120)': x=(w-text_h)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: fontsize=32: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5:" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android, If you are using ffmpeg-kit. Use Gpl libarary for "libx264"

```
 implementation 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full-gpl:5.1'
```

For position

```
    var POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT = "x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10"
    var POSITION_TOP_RIGHT = "x=w-tw-10:y=10"
    var POSITION_TOP_LEFT = "x=10:y=10"
    var POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT = "x=10:h-th-10"
    var POSITION_CENTER_BOTTOM = "x=(main_w/2-text_w/2):y=main_h-(text_h*2)"
    var POSITION_CENTER_ALLIGN = "x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/3"
```

Then

```
  val command = StringBuilder()
                .append("-y") //overWrite
                .append(" -i ").append(videoFile!!.path)  // video
                .append(" -vf ").append("drawtext=").append("text=").append(text)
                .append(":fontcolor=").append(color).append(":").append("fontsize=")
                .append(size + border).append(":").append(position)
                .append(":fontfile=").append(font!!.path)
                .append(" -c:v libx264 ").append(" -c:a copy  -movflags +faststart ")
                .append(outputFile.path)
```

Run the ffmpeg

```
     val session = FFmpegKit.execute(command.toString())

     if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(session.returnCode)) {

           callback!!.onFinish()


            // SUCCESS
       } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(session.returnCode)) {
                   
            callback!!.onFailure("CANCELLED")


       } else {

            callback!!.onFailure("FAILED "+  String.format(
                        "Command failed with state %s and rc %s.%s",
                        session.state,
                        session.returnCode,
                        session.failStackTrace
      ))}
```

Comment: hi @Rohaitas can we connect ? i have doubts regarding ffmpegkit could u help?

Comment: @Wini  whats the issue?

Comment: the command which u used above not working for me ... file is created but when i tried to play its not playing video video cannot played @Rohaitas

Comment: do check file extension. it was working for me

Comment: check logs as well

Comment: do u have any sample project on github so that i can refer???
i need for adding text,music , filter using ffmpeg in  video

Comment: adding music is very easy adding text and image is difficult because of position. You need to  calculate percentage of video mobile videoplayer. scaling image their resolution. It is complex.
https://pastebin.com/369b6zk8

Comment: Hi rohaitas ...thanks for sharing code snippet...but adding the add text on video command it is going on last else part ... after debugging session came as  ->AVFilterGraph @ 0xb400007ae12f9c00] No such filter: 'drawtext'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Filter not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: can u tell me ur ffmpeg kit version??

Comment: you can use full-gpl but if you want to reduce app size. use min-gpl.  but min gpl doesn't allow to add text. convert text to image. then use a single command to add multiple image. i was using version 5.1

Comment: ok.. i have now switched to full 6.0-2 now it is giving error to me like Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xb400007ae12ef470] Error initializing filters
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory can u guide?

Comment: i am busy. save the font file from raw resource to filedir. then use it.
        String fontFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "font.ttf").getAbsolutePath();

Comment: save font and stickers to FIleDir  and also temp  output file. as it doesn't need storage permission