# ffmpeg - title to display throughout the video duration

Tags: ffmpeg, title

I have used the `ffmpeg` package to create a `wmv` file from `gif` (please see below).  The title displays for a few seconds, then disappears.  Is there a setting I can apply, in order to have the title appearing in the video throughout the duration?

```
ffmpeg -i Input.gif -s 300x300 -metadata title="Testing" Output.wmv
```

Following the suggestion by Maxito, I have modified the code to

```
ffmpeg -i Input.gif -vf drawtext="text='Text to write is this one,     overlaid':fontsize=20:fontcolor=red:x=100:y=100" Output_Text.wmv
```

The following error message was received:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x100115cc0] No such filter: 'drawtext'
Error opening filters!
```

This is the version of ffmpeg I used on Mac 10.6.8.  Is there a need to re-compile?

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.3
built on Jan 19 2015 13:08:24 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Comment: If by display you mean "in vlc" that's a client/playback thing, not an encoding thing, FWIW

Comment: Thanks, @rogerdpack. Is there a way to add a text to the video file that will appear in every frame using ffmpeg?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text on video ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg)

Comment: Looks like now that he's got the command right, the question is about the `AVFilterGraph` error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error with `AVFilterGraph` and `drawtext` happens when your ffmpeg is compiled without libfreetype.

To generate images with text, you need to compile ffmpeg with libfreetype. The easiest way to do this is with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Assuming homebrew is already installed:

```
# If ffmpeg is already installed, you need to uninstall it.
brew uninstall ffmpeg

# you may very well want to specify other options (e.g. --with-faac)
brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing that typo, @LordNeckbeard

Comment: This has to be taken as answer as the --libfreetype is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download a `ffmpeg` binary for OS X](http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) if you don't want to compile. It contains support for libfreetype which is required for [drawtext](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter.

Users of other OS can get binaries via links on the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.