# ffmpeg moving text drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I'm using ffmpeg library to draw text on video in specific time and i'm success to  do that Now i need to move the text from position to another and i can't do that  so can any one suggest me how to do that

i'm using this command to move text from  top to down but i can't determine the x and Y to move from the x,y to specific x,y

```
ffmpeg -i VideoInput.mp4 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,14)':fontfile=myfont.otf:text='Test test':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=w/50\*mod(t\,2):fontsize=65" -acodec copy outputVideo.mp4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i VideoInput.mp4 \
       -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,14)':fontfile=myfont.otf:text='Test test': \
           x='x1+(x2-x1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1)':y='y1+(y2-y1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1)':fontsize=65" \
       -acodec copy outputVideo.mp4
```

where

`x1` and `y1` are initial co-ordinates;
`x2` and `y2` are final co-ordinates;
`t1` and `t2` are start and end times; in your given command, `12` and `14`.

These above need to be replaced with their values in the command.

---

To give a 1 second stay at the end,

```
ffmpeg -i VideoInput.mp4 \
       -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,15)':fontfile=myfont.otf:text='Test test': \
           x='if(lt(t-t2+1\,0)\,x1+(x2-x1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1-1)\,x)': \
           y='if(lt(t-t2+1\,0)\,y1+(y2-y1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1-1)\,y)':fontsize=65" \
       -acodec copy outputVideo.mp4
```

Here `t2` includes the stay, so movement from 12 to 14 + 1 second hold. The `t2` in enable is changed as well.

Comment: Thanks it's works fine for me, but i have another question if you can answer it, after the end time the text  disappear can i make it stay visible for 1 sec with no move then it disappear

Comment: Hello  my friend i want to know one more info about moving text using ffmpeg
can i control the speed of moving text? because i want to speed it up
i'm trying to google it but i can found the solution
so if you have any idea please help 
Thansk

Comment: Change the stay value `1` e.g. if you want the motion to occur from 12 to 13, then change `1`s to `2`s  so `lt(t-t2+1\,0)` becomes `lt(t-t2+2\,0)`. Same for all other expressions in the command.