# Speed of moving text drawtext filter - FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I'm using this command to move text from one place to another using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i VideoInput.mp4 \
       -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,14)':fontfile=myfont.otf:text='Test test': \
           x='x1+(x2-x1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1)':y='y1+(y2-y1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1)':fontsize=65" \
       -acodec copy outputVideo.mp4
```

Now I need to control the speed of moving the text. I want to speed it up.
How do I control the speed?

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here

using this command

```
ffmpeg -i VideoInput.mp4 \
       -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,15)':fontfile=myfont.otf:text='Test test': \x='if(lt(t-t2+1\,0)\,x1+(x2-x1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1-1)\,x)': \
           y='if(lt(t-t2+1\,0)\,y1+(y2-y1)*(t-t1)/(t2-t1-1)\,y)':fontsize=65" \
       -acodec copy outputVideo.mp4
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498026/4826602