# FFMPEG utf-8 special character not working in video watermark text

Tags: php, video, utf-8, ffmpeg

```
$input = "input.flv";
$output = "output.mp4";
$font = "arial.ttf";
$text = "ମୋ ପ୍ରତିଭା";

$command = "ffmpeg -i $input -vf \"format=yuv444p, drawbox=y=ih/PHI:color=black@0.4:width=iw:height=48:t=max, drawtext=fontfile=$font:text='$text':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=w-tw:y=(h/PHI)+th, format=yuv420p\" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart $output";
```

**Result:**

[image]

Here I want to put utf-8 character. But I am anable to get proper text in my video output. Please help me.

Comment: What encoding is your source code?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack See my screenshot text above my question.

Comment: That's not what I asked. What encoding is your source code saved in?

Comment: @Chinmay235 Did you find any solution for this problem, or this is just encoder specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Arial font file with the Unicode characters is called `arialuni.ttf`. Odia characters print correctly here with that font.

Comment: Same output coming

Comment: Show full command and console output.

Comment: I have not run my code in console. I just run in my web page.

Comment: Wait I am running...

Comment: Yes this is working in console. But not working in browser. :(

Comment: Here is my console output - http://imgur.com/hBxKeyw

Comment: Here is my temporary URL please check - http://202.191.214.174/phygee/ffmpeg/  Enter watermark text. Put any video. watermark type = text, position=center, input type=video, output type= video.