# ffmpeg drawtext how to set direction right to left

Tags: video, ffmpeg, right-to-left, freetype, drawtext

i write arabic text to videos and it works fine but the issue is that the arabic language is written from right to left
so the text must align right not left
i get the text like this
[image]

and it should be like this

 [image]

 my code

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text_shaping=1:fontfile=C\/:/Windows/Fonts/tradbdo.ttf:\
textfile=text-new.txt:fontcolor=white:fontsize=40:x=w-tw:y=h-50*t:" -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the `subtitles` centers the text by default, which is good, but it still doesn't set the right-to-left mode. In HTML, you would do this with `<div dir="rtl">`. The most obvious error resulting from this bug is that the full stop at the end of sentences is put all the way to the right, instead of all the way to the left.

Comment: this is worked for me as well as i desired. i try to move text by x , y in command

Comment: Any luck solving the issue? @Abdalla

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: what if i want to use drawtext instead of subtitles?