# Sendcmd in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Why `sendcmd` in ffmpeg works with `drawtext`, but does not work with `scale`, `rotation` and other filters?

Example (this code works)

```
ffmpeg  -i testIN.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=testTXT.cmd,drawtext=fontfile=PF.ttf:text='': fontcolor=white:fontsize=150" testOUT.mp4
```

testTXT.cmd

```
0 drawtext reinit 'text=111';
1 drawtext reinit 'text=222';
2 drawtext reinit 'text=333';
```

Example (this code does not work)

```
ffmpeg -i testIN.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=testTXT.cmd,drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100" testOUT.mp4
```

testTXT.cmd

```
0 drawbox reinit 'x=20:y=20:w=200:h=200';
1 drawbox reinit 'x=30:y=30:w=300:h=300';
2 drawbox reinit 'x=40:y=40:w=400:h=400';
```

Comment: `drawbox` doesn't have command support.

Comment: @Makes You can see which filters support sendcmd with `ffmpeg -filters`. Look for a "`C`" to the left of the filter name.

Comment: Thanks, I checked, the rotation filter supports the command, but the code does not work.  

`ffmpeg  -i testIN.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=testTXT.cmd,rotate=45*PI/180" testOUT.mp4`  

testTXT.cmd  
`0 rotate reinit '45*PI/180';
1 rotate reinit '90*PI/180';
2 rotate reinit '180*PI/180';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are encountering several issues:

1. Not all filters support [sendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd). You can see which filters support sendcmd with `ffmpeg -filters`. Look for a "`C`" to the left of the filter name. Additionally, only certain filter options (aka sendcmd "commands") can be used with sendcmd. See the [FFmpeg filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html), or refer to `man ffmpeg-filters`, and view the available options under the *Commands* section for each filter.
2. Each filter command must be declared in the sendcmd file. The `reinit` shown in the documentation example appears to be limited to the drawtext filter, but this is not explained in the documentation.

## rotate example

Example sendcmd text file:

```
    0 rotate angle '45*PI/180';
    1 rotate angle '90*PI/180';
    2 rotate angle '180*PI/180';
```

Example `ffmpeg` command:

```
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=test.cmd,rotate" output.mp4
```

The above example will rotate on duration `0`, `1`, and `2`.

## overlay example

Example sendcmd text file:

```
0
overlay@1 x 10,
overlay@1 y 10,
overlay@2 x W-w-10,
overlay@2 y H-h-10,
overlay@3 x (W-w)/2,
overlay@3 y (H-h)/2;

# overlay@1 does not move at this duration so it needs no new entry here
2.25
overlay@2 x 10,
overlay@2 y H-h-10,
overlay@3 x (W-w)/2,
overlay@3 y H-h-10;
```

Example `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i overlay1.png -i overlay2.jpg -i overlay3.png -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=test.cmd,nullsink;[0:v][1:v]overlay@1[bg1];[bg1][2:v]overlay@2[bg2];[bg2][3:v]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: What is the syntax for the overlay filter?

Comment: @Makes Example added.