# Hide or show overlay with sendcmd

Tags: ffmpeg

[Sendcmd in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581846/sendcmd-in-ffmpeg/54411432#54411432)

Can I hide the overlay and then show it with sendcmd?

Comment: Yes, set overlay position to out of frame e.g. x W.

Comment: Trying the posted example <br/> ```ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i overlay1.png -i overlay2.jpg -i overlay3.png -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=test.cmd,nullsink;[0:v][1:v]overlay@1[bg1];[bg1][2:v]overlay@2[bg2];[bg2][3:v]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output.mp4```<br/> it gives me error  ```No such filter: 'overlay@1'```<br/>What can be wrong???

Comment: @Gyan  thanks for the answer. Do you know what problem with error ```No such filter: 'overlay@1'``` ?

Comment: Used ffmpeg-2.7.2 and it not works. Just updating to the latest from git and it works.