# How create synth with FFMPG?

Tags: ffmpeg, synth

I am looking for the creation of a synth (synthé in french) with FFMPEG. For more explanation, a synth is a rectangle on a movie, where you can write text. In France, we had a very good science program on TV which have an example of the synth I'd like : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR7HojWY-kg from 11:50 to 11:54 where it is written "Dr Luc DE HARO". As this example, I'd like to add on the left a image. I am looking for weeks to do that but I can't realise this synth. Could you help me please ?

Comment: What you're referring to is commonly called a "lower third" and is usually created with software such as Adobe After Effects.  From there, a video with alpha channel can be exported and combined with FFmpeg, or can be put together in the composition directly in After Effects or in Premiere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text on video ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg)

Comment: not the same question :-), The result I want is different :-)

Comment: It isn't clear from your question *why* you want to do this with FFmpeg, which is important.  Is the text dynamic?  Coming from a script of some kind?  If not, just make the graphic asset in something else and composite it with FFmpeg.  Or, some other tool.

Comment: I'd like to use FFMPEG for create scripts (on mac and Linux only) but if you have other solution on **command line** (with free tools), I am very open to ear you. The text will change every time I launch the command

Comment: To change the text each time, you'll need to use that link I flagged your question as a duplicate of.

Comment: OK, I am agree with you but there is a big difference with the example : there is NO IMAGE on the left of th text and I don't understand how we do for create a "block" text+image (as the french example I have showed)

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg  You have to do the image and the text as two parts.

Comment: Oh I have never seen this website. Thanks a lot. I think it is a very good solution, I will  test now !

Comment: Hey Brad, thanks a lot, I think it is THE solution ! I have to write somme other thing to have a beautiiful synth but you have unblock me. Thx a lot