# ffmpeg cli filter that require user input

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to script filters for ffmpeg, such that when ever I give an input, the filter will change behavior?

An example would be changing contrast with a key, or blending two videos with another key, while recording the stream.

I've seen I could do this in a static way, like restart recording with the new behavior, and calling for a concat after, this results in some frame loss because of the process killing and process lifiting, but I wanted to know If this is possible, with out calling for restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [zmq and azmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) filters. Unlike the sendcmd filter, which uses pre-written commands, (a)zmq allows you arbitrarily to send filter commands.

To enable these filters you need to install the libzmq library and headers and configure `ffmpeg` with `--enable-libzmq`.

Only filters that support commands can be used with this filter. Refer to the output of `ffmpeg -filters` to view a list of which filters support commands. Additionally, not all options for a filter are considered to be commands. Refer to the documentation of each filter for a list of supported commands.

---

## Examples from the documentation

Consider the following filtergraph generated by ffplay. In this example the last overlay filter has an instance name. All other filters will have default instance names.

```
ffplay -dumpgraph 1 -f lavfi "
color=s=100x100:c=red  [l];
color=s=100x100:c=blue [r];
nullsrc=s=200x100, zmq [bg];
[bg][l]   overlay     [bg+l];
[bg+l][r] overlay@my=x=100 "
```

To change the color of the left side of the video, the following command can be used:

```
echo Parsed_color_0 c yellow | tools/zmqsend
```

To change the right side:

```
echo Parsed_color_1 c pink | tools/zmqsend
```

To change the position of the right side:

```
echo overlay@my x 150 | tools/zmqsend
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for *sendcmd*, which is supported by several filters. See the [FFmpeg filters documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) (search for sendcmd).