# ffmpeg - Overlay a text over a background image

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

The following command line for encoding audio with an image works fine.

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 15 -i  "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Kites.jpg" -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myaudio.mp3"  -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Out.mp4"
```

I want to overlay text over an image in the video frame. Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg), I added an overlay text like so. Since I want to use the default font, I skip the `drawtext="fontfile="` command deliberately like so. But now no video frames are visible, not even the background image. How can I do it? Thanks.

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 15 -i  "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Kites.jpg" -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myaudio.mp3"  -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -vf drawtext="text='Hello World': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2"   -c:a aac -shortest "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Out.mp4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine simple filters with a comma (`,`):

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 15 -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Kites.jpg" -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myaudio.mp3" -c:v libx264 -vf "drawtext=text='Hello World': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2,format=yuv420p" -c:a aac -shortest "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Out.mp4"
```

See [filtering introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for more info.