# Python adding text and combining video files

Tags: python, video, text, concatenation, overlay

i have been stcuk on this for multible hours now as my computer is not running moviepy i need to know if there is any other way to combine videos and add text in a python script please.

this is my code:

```
for i in names:
x = 0
Ftd = dird[x]#directory of file 
x = x + 1

clip = VideoFileClip("'"+Ftd+"'")
txt_clip = TextClip(str(i), fontsize = 20, color = 'White')
txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('top').set_duration(5)
video =  CompositeVideoClip([clip,txt_clip])
clips.append(video)

final = concatenate_videoclips(clips,method='compose')
final.write_videofile("done.mp4")
```

please i need help is there any other modules i can use or even cmd code that i can run with my python script.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to use a Python wrapper for ffmpeg - this will allow you leverage all the video processing functionality of ffmpeg from within Python.

There are several Python ffmpeg wrappers including:

- https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

FFMPEG is very feature rich and there are often multiple ways to achieve a particular goal, so it is worth doing some reading or web searching but as a starter for adding text:

- Documetation - http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1
- Good example command - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/334402

And for concatenating video:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

For concatenation it is worth looking at the options carefully as the best approach will depend on how similar the two videos are - if they use the same codecs you will likely be able to use a much less processor intensive concatenation approach.