# How to include font in FFMPEG command without using the fontfile option?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command to add watermark in my video using font TIMESNEWROMAN:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf "drawtext=text='© Krishna':fontfile=C//:/Windows/Fonts/times.ttf:x=(main_w-text_w-10):y=(main_h-text_h-10):fontsize=32:fontcolor=black:box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5: boxborderw=5" -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

Now, I want to provide the font TIMESNEWROMAN or any other font instead of fontfile path. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Use the `font` option

If your `ffmpeg` was compiled with `--enable-libfontconfig` you can use the `font` option. From the [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

> `font`
> The font family to be used for drawing text. By default `Sans`.

## Example

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf "drawtext=text='© Krishna':font='Times New Roman':x=(main_w-text_w-10):y=(main_h-text_h-10):fontsize=32:fontcolor=black:box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5:boxborderw=5" output.mp4
```

## To check for libfontconfig support

To check if your `ffmpeg` has `--enable-libfontconfig` just run the `ffmpeg` command with no options and it will output the configuration. Then look for `--enable-libfontconfig`.

## If you don't have libfontconfig

- **Windows** users can [download `ffmpeg` from BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) which includes libfontconfig support.
- **macOS** users can [download `ffmpeg` from evermeet.cx](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) or use Homebrew with the `--with-fontconfig` option.
- **Linux** users can [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Comment: Hi @llogan, I didnt find any windows build [here](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) which includes libfontconfig support. Is there any way to configure it?

Comment: @AvinashModi I downloaded `ffmpeg-N-100126-g0a5ff19643-win64-gpl.zip` from BtbN and it had `--enable-libfontconfig`. I tried it with `font` and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I got it.