How to run FFMPEG with --enable-libfontconfig on Amazon Linux 2
Problem
I want to run FFmpeg on AWS Lambda (Amazon Linux 2) with the configuration --enable-libfontconfig enable.
Situation
I already have FFmpeg running on AWS Lambda without the configuration --enable-libfontconfig.
Here is the step I took to run FFmpeg on AWS Lambda (see official guide):

Connect to Amazon EC2 running on AL2 (environment used by Lambda for Python 3.11)
Download and package FFmpeg from John Van Sickle
Create a Lambda Layer with FFmpeg

Unfortunately, the version built by John Van Sickle doesn't have the configuration --enable-libfontconfig enabled.
Unsuccessful Trials
I tried to rebuilt it from scratch following the installation guide but without success (and the guide doesn't install font related dependencies)
I tried to install it with brew but the command brew install ffmpeg didn't succeed on AL2.
I tried to install ffmpeg from ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar.xz. Unfortunately, this build of ffmpeg doesn't run on AL2:
ffmpeg: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ffmpeg)
ffmpeg: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ffmpeg)
ffmpeg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ffmpeg)
ffmpeg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ffmpeg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Please make sure your answer is up to date and tested. Too many answers out there are auto-generated, too generic, or simple redirect without context.
Thank you

Get the  ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar.xz from https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases

Have you tried this (the comment)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002949/how-to-include-font-in-ffmpeg-command-without-using-the-fontfile-option

@Gyan can you please include how to extract and build FFmpeg from the releases you sent. I'll try using the same instruction as for John Van Sickle build, and keep this thread updated. Thank you.

@BiRuVN yes thank you, I tried to follow, that's the installation guide I sent in my question. Unfortunately this answer is pretty generic and not very helpful (the answer just says 'build it yourself" with some extra words...)

@Gyan can you add information, your solution doesn't work alone. I used the .tar you suggested to create the Lambda Layer I got the following error when running ffmpeg -version in AWS Lambda: ffmpeg: /lib64/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ffmpeg) | ffmpeg: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version 'GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ffmpeg) | ffmpeg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ffmpeg) | ffmpeg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ffmpeg).
Please can you make sure you tested your answer first.

glibc is the C library provided by the OS. glibc 2.28 was released almost 6 years ago. Upgrade your OS. This is not an issue of the ffmpeg binary.

@Gyan unfortunately I cannot upgrade my OS. I don't control the OS AWS Lambda is running on. Do you know how could I find a version of ffmpeg working on 2.26 (version used by AWS Lambda) please?

@Gyan, I tested manually all version of FFmpeg from BtbN repo, they started using glibc > 2.6 on the release of 2024-03-31 17:38. The builds released before are running on AL2. Unfortunately none of the build running on glibc <= 2.26 support enable-libfontconfig. Thus, using builds from BtnN repo won't work. Do you have other solutions please?

It's fontconfig, not libfontconfig and all of BtbN builds include it: https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/blob/master/scripts.d/35-fontconfig.sh#L6

@Gyan, it is libfontconfig, see official documentation https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1. fontconfig is a different configuration.

No, it's not. See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/20206e14d7480d514b5e9cdda179dedd2742d4dd/configure#L6861

I am not sure I follow you, sorry ... The link you shared directly point to the configuation libfontconfig. Right, the option comes from a dependency package, does it change something? Do you mean that you can run font option from drawtext with only fontconfig and not libfontconfig? That's not what the documentation says, and my attempts to drawtext with font configs without libfontconfig failed. If you managed to make the documentation wrong, please share a working a example, I am very curious. Please also elaborate on your "it's not" as your link is confusing. Thank you.

My apologies, after multiple trials, I manage to run drawtext on AL2023 (used for Python3.12) with the build from BtbN. Thank you for your help @Gyan. (I still don't understand the difference between "libfontconfig" and "fontconfig" though..)

libfontconfig and fontconfig are the same dependency. fontconfig is the actual library name. The term with the lib- prefix is how ffmpeg configure originally labelled the package.
