# I want to add text to video using kotlin language in android. How can I do it.?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add text to video using kotlin language in android. How can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [FFmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) for that which is a video processing library. check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/12401637) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for  answer. Alright how to use with kotlin or android ?