# ffmpeg: New text after a few seconds without having both texts at the same time for one frame

Tags: ffmpeg

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg) answer was very usefull for me to learn how to include texts in a video using ffmepg. Now at one position of the video I want to always show a text but it changes. So what I did is for one text I used for example `enable='between(t,0,5)'` and for the next `enable='between(t,5,10)'`. Now at the frame at 5 seconds the video shows both texts. That is not what I want. I guess the reason is that `enable='between(t,0,5)'` includes the boundaries of the interval. So I somehow need ffmpeg to stop showing the first text one frame earlier. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "t>=t0 AND t<t1" logic":

```
enable='gte(t,0)*gt(t,5)'
enable='gte(t,5)*gt(t,10)'
```

Alternately, if your video is cfr (constant frame rate), then use frame index instead. For example, if fps=30, t=5 -> n=150 and t=10 -> n=300. Accordingly,

```
enable='between(n,0,149)'
enable='between(n,150,300)'
```

Finally, you can do a hack-job:

```
enable='between(t,0,4.999)'
```

You can read up more on FFmpeg expressions [in the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)